# antd currency inputNumber accept only number

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to have an InputNumber that has a thousand separators and at the same time only accepts numeric values, if I use type="number" I can't show "," separators and if I don't put it I can't prevent non-numeric from entering.
for example, this one accepts non-numeric and if I add another replace to remove non-numeric at the end, it won't work either  and as I said adding type="number" prevents showing "," separator

```
<Form.Item name="amount" label="">
                                <InputNumber
                                    formatter={(value) => {
                                        return `${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                                    }}
                                />
                            </Form.Item>
```

and this one doesn't work either [issues/10975](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/10975)

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

This particular fix will just remove the non numeric values excluding comma.
However `InputNumber` seems runs the `onChange` when you unfocus. So if you want to deliberately not accept alphabet this code is not going to cut it.
You probably just need to create your own Input with your own formatter.

```
function onNumericInputChange(value) {
  const reg = /^-?\d*(\.\d*)?$/;
  if ((!isNaN(value) && reg.test(value)) || value === "" || value === "-") {
    return value;
  }
  return false;
}

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: 24 }}>
      <p style={{ marginBottom: 24 }}>
        Current antd version: {version} <br />
        You can change antd version on the left panel (Dependencies section).
      </p>
      <InputNumber
        formatter={(value) => {
          console.log(value);
          return `${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        }}
        onChange={(value) => {
          const parsed = onNumericInputChange(value);
          console.log(parsed);
          if (parsed) {
            setValue(parsed);
          }
        }}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Fiddle here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-design-start-forked-r61vn?file=/index.js